# Wordpress : what is the best solution to convert to static files?

Tags: html, wordpress

I have several Wordpress websites on my shared hosting. The result is that my ressources are often important, and I would like to easily convert my wordpress in static html files.
The plugins available don't work, and with winhttrack, I create many redirection files.
Have-you the solution to make static Wordpress websites ?
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

A caching plugin like wp-rocket (paid) will serve static files on your server thus reducing resource drain.  A caching plugin will also keep the data live so you dont have to churn the static pages every time you update the content.

For actual static sites I use wget.  It may be a bit complicated to setup on your system depending on your set up - so how to do it is a different question. [For Windows 10 you can search here.](https://www.google.com/search?q=How%20to%20download%20your%20website%20using%20WGET%20for%20Windows&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t)